# Prevent other users from file access SVN Get Lock

Tags: svn, locking, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I was used to using VSS but have switch to SVN -using VisualSVN as server and  tortoiseSVN as client.

What i want is when some user wants to edit the file, he should do getlock. After that, that file should not become editable for the other users. This is the way VSS used to work.

I know that doing this may defeat the purpose of having different users work on the same file and later merging them,but i still need to do this.

I believe SVN also provides hooks for get lock command so we can insert a script there that  would send an email, but instead of email, i want to have the other users notify via svn getlock window itself when they do the getlock on the file which is locked out by some user.

If same can be achieved in visual studio, that would be best for me. Any free plugin supporting visualsvn should work.

Any idea about how to achieve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SVN's Lock-Unlock model [is possible](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html) workflow, but not recommended:

- it's not reliable (lock can be broken or stolen)
- it's time-waster

Edit-update or branch-merge model recommended for parallel work, when pieces of work can be merged by hand

**or**

Sequential work with the agreement of the sequence of operations using ordinary human2human communications, when merge not possible technically (see sample aroung graphic's designers in SVN Book)

Comment: Lock-modify-unlock can be controlled by Subversion hooks. Therefore, locking policies can be implemented to prevent broken or stolen locks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have used Tortoise-SVN and locks, whenever a file is locked by some other user, Tortoise warns you about it when you try to "get lock". In such cases, there is an option to "steal locks".

Thus, one has to explicitly do a get lock to know if a file is locked. To make this mandatory one can use subversion property "svn:needs-lock" which will make all files read-only and can be edited only after a lock is acquired. So if a file is locked by an user, this is the time when the other user knows about. There is no way to notify that user otherwise.

More information is available here:- http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html